# Apache2.4のユーザーディレクトリでシンボリックリンクを読めない

Tags: centos, apache

■環境
Server version: Apache/2.4.6 (CentOS)
CentOS Linux release 7.3.1611 (Core)
での質問です。

/home に2017、2016、2015 ... というディレクトリがあり、それぞれの中にその年度毎のユーザディレクトリが存在しています。

/home/public_html を作成し、その中に
hogetaro -> /home/2017/hogetaro/public_html
foohanako -> /home/2016/foohanako/public_html

といったシンボリックリンクを張り、

/etc/httpd/conf.d/userdir.conf に

```
<Directory "/home/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
    Options FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

と記述しユーザ毎のウェブディレクトリが表示出来るようにしようとしました。

しかし、アクセスすると Forbiddenとなり、error.logには

client denied by server configuration

と書かれていました。
どうすれば解決出来るでしょうか？

ちなみに、

```
<Directory "/home/*/*/public_html">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

とした時は問題なく表示できました。

Comment: 「UserDir public_html」を有効にして http://(server)/~hogetaro/ でアクセスしているのですか、それとも、「DocumentRoot "/home/public_html"」にして http://(server)/hogetaro/ でアクセスしているのですか？

Comment: @TaichiYanagiya  前者の方です。Documentrootは/var/www/htmlとしてます。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`UserDir public_html` を有効にして http://(server)/~hogetaro/ でアクセスしているとのこと。

hogetaro ユーザーのホームディレクトリが /home/2017/hogetaro/ ならば、`/~hogetaro/` というリクエストパスに対し、Apache httpd は `/home/2017/hogetaro/public_html/` を参照しますので、このディレクトリ(または親ディレクトリ)へのアクセス許可(Require all granted)が必要です。

/home/public_html/ 以下を参照するわけではないので、`<Directory "/home/public_html">` で許可しても、FollowSymLinks を有効にしても関係ありません。

Comment: 分かりました！回答ありがとうございます！